# Defining a global variable inside a class vs. defining inside a method

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I am trying to find the vertical width if a binary tree as defined in this link; https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/batch/dsa-4/track/DSASP-Tree/problem/vertical-width-of-a-binary-tree

My question is regarding defining a global variable inside a class vs defining it inside a method. Here is my code, which is working as expected in the present form;

```
   class Node:
    #global dnew

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def vertical_width(self):
        #dnew = {self.data: 0}
        #print(self.data, dnew)
        if self is None:
            return
        # if we move left decrease value by 1
        if self.left != None:
            dnew[self.left.data] = dnew[self.data] - 1
            self.left.vertical_width()
        print('left', dnew)
        # if we move right increase value by 1
        if self.right != None:
            dnew[self.right.data] = dnew[self.data] + 1
            self.right.vertical_width()
        print('right', dnew)
        return dnew

    def mainfn(self):
       global dnew
       dnew = {self.data:0}
       result = self.vertical_width()
       return len(set(result.values()))


class Tree:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root


# define a tree as an example to test the code 
node = Node(1)
node.left = Node(2)
node.left.left = Node(3)
node.left.right = Node(4)
node.right = Node(5)
#node.right.left = Node(6)
mytree = Tree(node)
res = mytree.root.mainfn()
```

Question is, if we just define `global dnew` inside the `Node` class rather than defining it inside the `mainfn()`, we get following error message;

`NameError: name 'dnew' is not defined`

But isn't that if we define a variable with global keyword, it shd be accessible by all methods in a class.Can I please get some help to understand this concept?

Comment: It has to be defined before the point where it is used. In your case, it is used in `vertical_width`, but not declared until `mainfn`, which is after `vertical_width`. The compiler can't see ahead of `vertical_width` to know about what is going to happen later in `mainfn`.

Comment: BTW, your example doesn't make much sense. `dnew` is only used inside `vertical_width`, so it has no need to be global at all - it could just be defined inside `vertical_width`.

Comment: Since you're presumably still learning, you should note that this is a _horrific_ use of a global variable. If that website is recommending using global variables in this way, you might want to consider never visiting it again and consulting a proper Python tutorial or book.

Comment: @Brian. it is true that I am in the learning stage right now. The reason I use `global` for `dnew` because I was trying to change it in every recursive call of the function. so that `dnew` is accessible to each recursive calls.

If possible, can you plz recommend an alternate soln. for this problem, which may not need use of global variable. It will be a learning experience and will be appreciated.

Comment: @jay A few possibilities, at increasing levels of complexity: 1) use a private helper function that accepts `dnew` as a parameter. E.g., the body of `vertical_width` would look like `return self._vertical_width({self.data: 0})` 2) create a "tree walker" class whose job is to walk the tree while maintaining some state (like `dnew`), 3) write a single [generator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1756096) method that walks your tree in BFS order and `yield`s each node in turn. Then write `vertical_height` as a single for loop `for node in self.bfs_nodes(): <update local variable dnew for left/right>`